# Tengo problema con la función ya de realizar compra

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.7

el funcionamiento la primera vez que aprieto el botón que llama a esta función es el correcto, pero al volver al realizar otra compra me da este error : **_tkinter.TclError: Item I001 not found**, y si quiero volver a realizarlo me tira que la base de datos fue bloqueada. No tengo idea como poder resolverlo, yo calculo que es cuando vuelve a pasar por cada fila del treeview. Desde ya muchas gracias.

```
def finalizar_compra(self):

    # Variables
    global usuario_logueado
    global nombre_empresa
    id_cliente = self.menu_clientesID.get()
    fecha = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
    total = self.suma_total.get()
    cliente = self.menu_clientes.get()

    db = sqlite3.connect('PDVdamoonplay.db')
    conexion = db.cursor()

    conexion.execute('INSERT INTO ventas VALUES(NULL,?,?,?,?)', (fecha,id_cliente,total,usuario_logueado))
    ultima_venta = conexion.lastrowid

    registro = 1
    for item in self.grilla_productos.get_children():

        id_prod = (self.grilla_productos.item("I"+ str(registro).zfill(3))['text'])
        producto = (self.grilla_productos.item("I"+ str(registro).zfill(3))['values'][0])
        cantidad = (self.grilla_productos.item("I"+ str(registro).zfill(3))['values'][1])
        precio = (self.grilla_productos.item("I"+ str(registro).zfill(3))['values'][2])
        subtotal = (self.grilla_productos.item("I"+ str(registro).zfill(3))['values'][3])
        
        # Conexion
        conexion.execute('INSERT INTO ventas_detalles VALUES(NULL,?,?,?,?)', (ultima_venta,id_prod, cantidad, precio))
        conexion.execute('UPDATE productos SET stock = stock - ? WHERE id = ? ', (cantidad, id_prod))

        registro += 1
    db.commit()
    print(ticket)
    messagebox.showinfo(title = 'Información', message =  'Venta realizada con exito!')
    self.eliminar_todo()
    self.menu_clientes.set('')
    self.menu_clientes.focus()
    conexion.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando borras todo el contenido del treeview los IDs de los items **no** se reinician.

Por ejemplo si tuvieras los item I001, I002 e I003 y los borras, El nuevo item que agregues será I004.

`tree.get_children()` devuelve una tupla con la id de cada item del Treeview. Iteras sobre el resultado de ello en un bucle for (sin embargo, nunca usas esa variable).

La solución es usar el id del item obtenido con `self.grilla_productos.get_children()`

###### Código

```
def finalizar_compra(self):

    # Variables
    global usuario_logueado
    global nombre_empresa
    id_cliente = self.menu_clientesID.get()
    fecha = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
    total = self.suma_total.get()
    cliente = self.menu_clientes.get()

    db = sqlite3.connect('PDVdamoonplay.db')
    conexion = db.cursor()

    conexion.execute('INSERT INTO ventas VALUES(NULL,?,?,?,?)', (fecha,id_cliente,total,usuario_logueado))
    ultima_venta = conexion.lastrowid

    for item in self.grilla_productos.get_children():

        id_prod = (self.grilla_productos.item(item)['text'])
        producto = (self.grilla_productos.item(item)['values'][0])
        cantidad = (self.grilla_productos.item(item)['values'][1])
        precio = (self.grilla_productos.item(item)['values'][2])
        subtotal = (self.grilla_productos.item(item)['values'][3])
        
        # Conexion
        conexion.execute('INSERT INTO ventas_detalles VALUES(NULL,?,?,?,?)', (ultima_venta,id_prod, cantidad, precio))
        conexion.execute('UPDATE productos SET stock = stock - ? WHERE id = ? ', (cantidad, id_prod))

    db.commit()
    print(ticket)
    messagebox.showinfo(title = 'Información', message =  'Venta realizada con exito!')
    self.eliminar_todo()
    self.menu_clientes.set('')
    self.menu_clientes.focus()
    conexion.close()
```

Comment: Ah buenisimo muchas gracias, suponía que tenia que ver con algo asi, pero en que momento exacto tengo que usar el en este caso grilla_productos.get_children()??

Comment: Cada vez que requieras conocer el id de los items a partir de su posicion o recorrer el treeview item por item. Depende de lo que quieras hacer.

Comment: Claro, justamente despues del self.eliminar_todo() que en teoría, seria cuando vuelvo a llenar la lista con los nuevos productos. pero probe despues de esa función y me sigue dando el mismo error

Comment: Bueno, tree.get_children() NO se actualiza automáticamente. Primero tendrías que eliminar todos los items, agregar los nuevos y luego hacer una segunda llamada a tree.get_children() para obtener los ids actualizados.

Comment: Okey, ahora si entendí muchas gracias!

Comment: De nada Dani c: