# Error en el treeview: Item I010 not found

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy realizando la misma app de compras de siempre, y ya finalizando con los retoques me tope con este problema: llego a cargar 9 productos traquilamente pero a la hora de ejecutar la compra en el item 10 me da el error de **Item I010 not found**. Supongo que es un error en  el indice pero no lo se con exactitud, realice un print en el INSERT donde se insertan en la tabla de ventas y cuando llega al producto 10 da ese error.

```
def finalizar_compra(self):

    # Variables
    global ingreso
    global usuario_logueado
    global nombre_empresa
    id_cliente = self.menu_clientesID.get()
    fecha = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
    total = self.suma_total.get()
    cliente = self.menu_clientes.get()

    db = sqlite3.connect('PDVdamoonplay.db')
    conexion = db.cursor()

    conexion.execute('BEGIN TRANSACTION;')
    conexion.execute('INSERT INTO ventas VALUES(NULL,?,?,?,?)', (fecha,id_cliente,total,usuario_logueado))
    ultima_venta = conexion.lastrowid

    registro = 1
    ticket = 'Comercio: ' + nombre_empresa +'\n'
    ticket = ticket + 'Cliente: '+ cliente[4:30] + '\n'
    ticket = ticket + 'Fecha: ' + str(fecha) + '\n' + '\n'   
    ticket = ticket + 'Cant'.ljust(3) + ' ' + 'Producto'.ljust(10) + ' ' + 'Precio'.rjust(10) + ' ' + 'Subtotal'.rjust(12) + '\n'
    ticket = ticket + '-'*39

    for item in self.grilla_productos.get_children():

        id_prod = (self.grilla_productos.item("I"+ str(registro).zfill(3))['text'])
        producto = (self.grilla_productos.item("I"+ str(registro).zfill(3))['values'][0])
        cantidad = (self.grilla_productos.item("I"+ str(registro).zfill(3))['values'][1])
        precio = (self.grilla_productos.item("I"+ str(registro).zfill(3))['values'][2])
        subtotal = (self.grilla_productos.item("I"+ str(registro).zfill(3))['values'][3])

        # Conexion
        query = conexion.execute('INSERT INTO ventas_detalles VALUES(NULL,?,?,?,?)', (ultima_venta,id_prod, cantidad, precio))
        print(query)
        conexion.execute('UPDATE productos SET stock = stock - ? WHERE id = ? ', (cantidad, id_prod))

        ticket = ticket + '\n' + str(cantidad).rjust(3) + '  ' + producto[9:18].ljust(10) + ' ' + str(precio).rjust(10) + ' ' + str(subtotal).rjust(12)

        registro += 1

    ticket = ticket +'\n'*2 + 'Total:'+ str(total).rjust(33)
    conexion.execute('INSERT INTO caja(id,fecha,descripcion,importe_ingreso,usuario) VALUES(NULL,?,?,?,?)',(fecha,ingreso,total,usuario_logueado))

    db.commit()

    print(ticket)
    messagebox.showinfo(title = 'Información', message =  'Venta realizada con exito!')
    self.eliminar_todo()
    self.menu_clientes.set('')
    self.menu_clientes.focus()
    conexion.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los ids predeterminados del treeview no se forman como piensas. Es decir, tu sistema va a andar bien cuando ingreses el item I009, pero el item 10 va a tener de id I00A. No existe el Item I010.

Para quitarte este problema de encima tienes dos caminos:

- Cada vez que agregues un item al treeview, usa ids personalizados. Esto tendría el costo de que cada vez que borres, por ejemplo, un solo item del treeview, tendrás que hacer que todos lo que le siguen adquieran una nueva id que sea su id anterior menos 1. Esto sirve, por ejemplo, para evitar huecos que resulten en que cada item tenga estos respectivos ids: `1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9`
- Simplemente usa `tree.get_children()` como te dije en [tu pregunta anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/529215/158880). Esta función devolverá una tupla con los ids de cada item en el orden que están en el treeview. Itera sobre eso y en vez de dejar la variable item sin uso, recurre a ella cada vez que requieras obtener la id de un item.

El código de tu for según la segunda idea quedaría así:

```
for item in self.grilla_productos.get_children():

    id_prod = (self.grilla_productos.item(item)['text'])
    producto = (self.grilla_productos.item(item)['values'][0])
    cantidad = (self.grilla_productos.item(item)['values'][1])
    precio = (self.grilla_productos.item(item)['values'][2])
    subtotal = (self.grilla_productos.item(item)['values'][3])

    # Conexion
    query = conexion.execute('INSERT INTO ventas_detalles VALUES(NULL,?,?,?,?)', (ultima_venta,id_prod, cantidad, precio))
    print(query)
    conexion.execute('UPDATE productos SET stock = stock - ? WHERE id = ? ', (cantidad, id_prod))

    ticket = ticket + '\n' + str(cantidad).rjust(3) + '  ' + producto[9:18].ljust(10) + ' ' + str(precio).rjust(10) + ' ' + str(subtotal).rjust(12)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda , siempre me salvas las papas jaja Igual me super sirvio, ahora si entiendo bien como funciona el treeview

Comment: De nada c: Y me alegro nwn